# Prevent Windows OS to access other partitions

Tags: partitioning, windows

I have three partitions of the SSD:

1. Ubuntu with all my work
2. partition for videos/photos
3. (here I want to install Windows 10 OS)

I would like that Windows 10 OS is "completely constrained" to the third partition. That it has no access to partitions 1 and 2, for security reasons.

How to do that?

Comment: Unless you encrypt partitions 1 and 2, you cannot.  Even if they are not mounted (or whatever terminology is used by Windows), Windows should at least see them and/or know that they're there.  What you seem to be asking for is to someone make Windows not even know the other two partitions exist.  I don't believe you can.

Comment: Thanks @Ray, actually I'm ok with windows knowing the partitions are there (or even know the partitions' meta-data like size), I just need to prevent it to be able to access (read) the content.

Comment: Unless you do encryption, I don't think you can.  A normal user has permission to mount a partition in Windows, I think.  That isn't the case with Linux/Ubuntu -- system administrator's access is required.  So, this is more of a problem of Windows allowing normal users to mount than Ubuntu/Linux allowing it to mount.  Perhaps you can create a user in Windows with a lower access level and see if it can be used to mount.  I think your problem is more of an issue for Windows than Linux.  I don't suggest you use encryption, because that opens up other potential problems.

Comment: "I would like that Windows 10 OS is "completely constrained" to the third partition. That it has no access to partitions 1 and 2, for security reasons." Impossible. Even with encrypyion you can delete the partition :-)  If you do not want Windows to touch Ubuntu do not put the on the same machine. And this is a windows problem... not Ubuntu... we take security serious and require a mandatory admin with admin password for these kind of actions ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can encrypt each one. LUKS for Linux and bitlocker for windows.

Comment: Thank you. Will this slow down the regular reading of media on partition 2., and my regular work on partition 1.?

Comment: I don't think so. You will have to unlock them each time you want to access them though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/ee449438(v=ws.10) There is a performance decrease. Same with LUKS. Mainly writing data.